# php quoting problem

Tags: php

I have this PHP code

```
echo '<a href="#" onclick="updateByQuery(\'Layer3\', ' . json_encode($query) . ');">Link 1</a>';
```

which generates a link like this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="updateByQuery('Layer3', "Ed Hardy");">Link 1</a><li>Link 2</li>
```

Causing the javascript to not be called. How would I make it generate single quotes around the result of $query, in this case ed hardy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to do the reverse... use single quotes for html, and double quotes for javascript. That's how we do that in fact.

Comment: I am unsure how to modify the echo line to sue both, as I must have double quotes around the JavaScript function. Do I just escape them?

Answer (score 2):

You should [html encode](http://www.php.net/htmlentities) it:

```
echo '<a href="#" onclick="updateByQuery(\'Layer3\', ' . htmlentities(json_encode($query)) . ');">Link 1</a>';
```

You could also use `htmlspecialchars`

Comment: that produces &quot instead of " which actually breaks it

Comment: Errr no, &quot; is what you want and will fix it for you.

Comment: @Joshxtothe4, &quot; is converted to " by the browser before it reaches the Javascript parser.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "<a href='#' onclick='updateByQuery(\"Layer3\", \"" . json_encode($query) . "\");'>Link 1</a>";
```

This produces:

```
<a href='#' onclick='updateByQuery("Layer3", "Ed Hardy");'>Link 1</a>
```

Comment: Not valid XHTML, but I won't -1 because he wants HTML it seems.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "<a href='#' onclick='updateByQuery(\"Layer3\", " . json_encode($query) . ");'>Link 1</a>";
```

Comment: Fixed the formatting for you - you need to select it and hit the Code Sample (binary icon) button

Comment: @Roborg; this produces:

<a href='#' onclick='updateByQuery("Layer3", Ed Hardy);'>Link 1</a>

Notice there are no quotes around Ed Hardy.

Answer (score 0):

Quotes are a problem with inline handlers. As RoBerg says, you need to use htmlentities in the text.

Another way around it is to use hook methods and anonymous functions, rather than inline handlers.

```
echo '
<a href="#" id="link_1">Link 1</a>
<script>document.getElementById("link_1").onclick =
       function() { updateByQuery("Layer3", '.json_encode($query).'); }
</script>
';
```